# Angularjs: Sharing data within instances of an app

Tags: angularjs, sharing

I am an angularjs newbie and ran in to issues with data sharing within instances of an app. What is the recommended way with respect to best practices, to share data between pieces within an instance of an app. I understand services can be used to share data within components of an app. But this becomes a problem when multiple copies of the app exist on the same page.

For instance a list which can be reordered by drag and drop is a good example. At this point I have created an instance of the service and passed it top down so that all components speak to the same instance. This way the service is instantiated only once per copy of the app. So I do have a solution but would like to know if there are better approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing. You have multiple copies of the same app on the same page, and want to share data between them? If you just have one app, and want to share data, then yes, a service is the right choice. And in angular, services are singletons, so everything does use the same instance.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I am referring to sharing data between components of an app and not between copies of an app.